# Is it possible to draw on an SFML window regardless of views?

Tags: c++, view, sfml

I have a game I'm currently working on, and it uses multiple views (for a minimap for example).

Thing is, I would like to have a fading effect added at some point, so I thought I'd create a black image that is the size of the screen and change its alpha value with a timer. That part is not a problem.

What happens right now is the main area (ie window default view) is fading (because the opacity of the image is increasing), but the minimap (minimap view) is unaffected. This is normal behaviour for views, but is there a way to draw an image to the whole window, regardless of the views ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe temporarily resetting the view?

Comment: @Hiura What do you mean by resetting ?

Comment: Something like this: `auto tmp = window.getView(); window.setView(window.getDefaultView()); /* draw your stuff */ window.setView(tmp);`

Comment: The game is drawn in the default view. What would be the point of the temporary view ?

Comment: Then you should explain better what you mean by "draw an image to the whole window".

Comment: I'll simplify : I have the content of the game drawn in the default view, and a second view with a minimap. I would like to draw something over the whole screen, not in one of the views. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: Well, the default view should draw on the whole window. Doesn't my previous comment work?

Comment: Nope, the minimap is not affected...

Comment: The last idea I have is make sure you draw your minimap before drawing this image... otherwise, I don't know. :/

Comment: Well the minimap is drawn in a different View, so whatever I draw on the default one will go behind it, therefore the order in which I draw doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, you have the default view where you'll draw the main game, then you'll have the minimap view where you would draw the minimap. At some point in the game you want the whole screen to fade to black. It sounds like you've been trying to draw a black image on the default view (changing the alpha) to make this effect work.

So, you need a third view that you draw your black image on to get this fading effect.

Comment: You are totally correct on your clarification. 
I thought of that, but I can't find the settings to a third view which wouldn't interfere with both others. I tried creating a view the size of the screen, and it appeared on top of the existing ones (or pushed them aside, i don't know)